# Что происходит с фиксированными дочерними элементами при трансформации родителя?

Tags: css, position, позиционирование, transform

Если у фиксированного элемента родитель как-то трансформируется, то этот самый фиксированный элемент ведет себя как абсолютно позиционированный. Почему? Как этого избежать?

В примере если проскроллить страницу и кликнуть (тем самым просто сместив всю обертку вправо), то фиксированный элемент уходит наверх, как будто принимает значение position: absolute.

```js
$('.wrapper').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('slide');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
}
.slide {
  transform: translate(100px, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="for_scroll">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates similique reprehenderit consequatur aliquam totam, aperiam autem, est reiciendis accusantium rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates similique reprehenderit consequatur aliquam totam, aperiam autem, est reiciendis accusantium rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Voluptates similique reprehenderit consequatur aliquam totam, aperiam autem, est reiciendis accusantium rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. Voluptates similique reprehenderit consequatur aliquam totam, aperiam autem, est reiciendis accusantium rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates
    similique reprehenderit consequatur aliquam totam, aperiam autem, est reiciendis accusantium rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates similique reprehenderit
    consequatur aliquam totam, aperiam autem, est reiciendis accusantium rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates similique reprehenderit consequatur
    aliquam totam, aperiam autem, est reiciendis accusantium rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates similique reprehenderit consequatur aliquam totam,
    aperiam autem, est reiciendis accusantium rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates similique reprehenderit consequatur aliquam totam, aperiam autem,
    est reiciendis accusantium rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates similique reprehenderit consequatur aliquam totam, aperiam autem, est reiciendis
    accusantium rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates similique reprehenderit consequatur aliquam totam, aperiam autem, est reiciendis accusantium
    rerum nobis. Quisquam quas porro et tenetur eius. Possimus dolorum, aut.
  </div>
  <div class="fixed">
    I'm fixed! What's going on?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А в IE прикольно - он sticky делает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что `transform` создает новую систему координат

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-rendering

Comment: И красное предупреждение, что с fixed они не очень-то и решили...